# PHP -> PDO Update Function using Foreach array merge

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, sql-update

The following code is supposed to check for the column names of a table. Then check to see if a corresponding variable has been $_POST and if it has add it to the $SQL. I believe there is a problem with the array that contains a series of arrays but I don't know how to dix it.

```
$where = $_POST['where'];
    $is = $_POST['is'];
    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET";
    $array = array();

    $columnnames = columnnames('blog');
    foreach ($columnnames as $columnname){

        if($_POST[$columnname]){
            $sql .= " $columnname = :$columnname,";
            $array .= array(':$columnname' => $_POST[$columnname],);
        }

    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql,',');
    $array = rtrim($array,',');

    $sql .= " WHERE $where = '$is'";
    $q = $rikdb->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($array);
```

For the sake of comprehension please except that `$columnnames = columnnames('blog');` works as it does.

Comment: **SQL injection alert!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$array .= array(':$columnname' => $_POST[$columnname],);
```

to this:

```
$array[':$columnname'] = $_POST[$columnname];
```

and after that use rtrim only on $sql.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here `$array .= array(':$columnname' => $_POST[$columnname],);`

you have a `,` part of the value which is not literal. change it to be like

```
$array .= array(':$columnname' => $_POST[$columnname] . ",");
```

You can also add your column names and values to an array and `implode(",", $array)` so you don't have to use `rtrim`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$array .= array(':$columnname' => $_POST[$columnname],);
```

and applying `rtrim` on results, I'd suggest the easier and failsafe method:

```
$array[':$columnname'] = $_POST[$columnname];
```